# Не работает отклик InlineKeyboardButton

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegrambots

Во время нажатия на кнопку прилетает вот такая вот ошибочка в консоль :

```
SEVERE: BOTSESSION
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Message.getText()" because "msg" is null
    at Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:21)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:306)`
```

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.updatingmessages.EditMessageText;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.InlineKeyboardMarkup;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.InlineKeyboardButton;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Message;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {


    public void onUpdateReceived(Update u) {
        Message msg = u.getMessage();
        String txt = msg.getText();

        if (txt.equals("/start")) {
            // Set variables
            long chat_id = u.getMessage().getChatId();

            SendMessage message = new SendMessage() // Create a message object object
                    .setChatId(chat_id)
                    .setText("start");
            try {
                execute(message); // Sending our message object to user
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else if  (txt.equals("/help")) {
            long chat_id = u.getMessage().getChatId();
            SendMessage message = new SendMessage()
                    .setChatId(chat_id)
                    .setText("buttons" + "\n");
            InlineKeyboardMarkup markupInline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
            List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> rowsInline = new ArrayList<>();
            List<InlineKeyboardButton> rowInline = new ArrayList<>();
            rowInline.add(new InlineKeyboardButton().setText("choose").setCallbackData("/choose"));
            // Set the keyboard to the markup
            rowsInline.add(rowInline);
            // Add it to the message
            markupInline.setKeyboard(rowsInline);
            message.setReplyMarkup(markupInline);
            try {
                execute(message);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (u.hasCallbackQuery()) {
            // Set variables
            String call_data = u.getCallbackQuery().getData();
            long message_id = u.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getMessageId();
            long chat_id = u.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId();

            if (call_data.equals("/choose")) {
                String answer = "choose";
                EditMessageText new_message = new EditMessageText()
                        .setChatId(chat_id)
                        .setMessageId(Math.toIntExact(message_id))
                        .setText(answer);
                try {
                    execute(new_message);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }





    public String getBotUsername() {
        // Return bot username
        // If bot username is @MyAmazingBot, it must return 'MyAmazingBot'
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        // Return bot token from BotFather
        return "";
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `getMessage()` может вернуть `null`, вызывайте `update.getMessage()` только после того, как сделаете проверку `update.hasMessage()`. Например, так:

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    if (update.hasMessage()) {
        Message message = update.getMessage();
        String text = message.getText();
        if (text.equals("/start")) {
            ...
        } else if (text.equals("/help")) {
            ...
        }
    } else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
        Message message = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage();
        ...
    }
}
```